# View JSON in Browser with PHP

Tags: php, json

I have a text file (called : data.txt) content below :

**My data.txt:**

```
["1","Ricky","23"],["2","Roy","24"],["3","Ryta","25"]
```

I want to view this data in browser with PHP, look like this:

[image]

I have read [php manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php), but stay confused.

I'm so sorry for my English.

Thank you very much for your lessons

Comment: What are you confused about? And what have you tried with `json_decode()`?

Comment: The problem is that is not VALID JSON

Comment: This is valid json `[
 ["1", "Ricky", "23"],
 ["2", "Roy", "24"],
 ["3", "Ryta", "25"]
]`

Comment: @Rizier123 :
in php manual, example of json is {"a":1,"b":2,"c":3,"d":4,"e":5}. this is different with my case.

Comment: try like that: `$decode = json_decode('['.$content.']');
foreach ($decode as $key => $value) {
  //echo values
}`

Comment: @flyingbird013 Dont amend a question. It makes answers and comments look like nonsence. I have reverted to the previous question edit. ___But you are welcome___

Comment: When creating a JSON string it is safest to make a PHP array or object containing the data you want, and then use `json_encode($var);` to created the JSON String in a valid way

Answer (score 0):

You need to correct your json:
Use this:

```
[["1","Ricky","23"],["2","Roy","24"],["3","Ryta","25"]]
```